# How can I secure hbase?

Tags: hbase

I'm using hbase on ec2 and just realized my scripts don't use a username/password to access hbase.  Is there a way to add simple username/password authentication?

Update: interested in something quick/dirty like mysql has with username creation and granting privileges.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to go the Kerberos route (**which is the best thing to do however**), and if your HBase requests are made from a single point (like an application server), you can always try to restrict the IP connections to the Zookeeper client.

The zookeeper client port is 2181 by default (see http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2013/07/guide-to-using-apache-hbase-ports/ for instance).

A simple way to do it is to use the `iptables` functionnality (if you are running linux), using something like :

```
iptables -A INPUT -i lo -m comment --comment "enable loopback connections" -j ACCEPT
# use the actual range of IPs that includes all of your cluster's nodes
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 2181 -m iprange --src-range '174.121.3.0-174.121.3.10' -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --destination-port 2181 -j DROP -m comment --comment "Disable tcp trafic toward port 2181 (zookeeper)"
# Export result so what it can be restored on reboot with iptables-restore < /etc/iptablesv4.conf (put it in something like /etc/rc.d/rc.local)
iptables-save > /etc/iptablesv4.conf
```

You need to do this on every node of the cluster because the HBase client will find any available zookeeper endpoint to make a successful connection.